# Язык страницы

Tags: кодировка, html

У меня такая проблема, на сайте у меня выскакивающее меню на javascript, CSS, jQuery. На русском языке. Когда добавил фотогалерею на тех же скриптах, но на английском, у меня с фотогалереей все ОК, а меню вместо русского показывает вопросики в ромбиках и название страницы русское, тоже ромбиками. Как решить такую проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зайдите на страницу, на которой не отображаются русские буквы. Посмотрите в меню браузера: Вид - Кодировка, что там браузер взял для этой страницы. И от этого уже можете плясать с бубном в мета тегах или кодировке страницы.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery плагины как правило в UTF-8 кодировке работают, потому вы в meta теге вашей страницы тоже пропишите UTF-8 и сам файл сохраните в этой же кодировке и будет все ОК.

Comment: UTF-8 и так стоит